# Add blank row to MySQL array at a specific point

Tags: mysql, arrays

I am pulling data from a MySQL DB, it is ordered by the serial number, however I want to add a blank row after one of the fields drops below it predecessor. for example.

```
Serial No. Hours. type
11111          5         1
11112          7         1
11113          12       1
11114          5         1
```

What I want is ...

```
Serial No. Hours. type
11111          5         1
11112          7         1
11113          12       1
Null             Null     Null
11114          5         1
```

Because the hours have dropped it add a blank line.

At the moment I use a simple Array to pull the data then loop it.

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably handle this in MySQL, but I vote for handling it in your view layer (PHP?).  To implement this in PHP might be less than 10 lines of code; in MySQL it would almost certainly be more than 10 lines.

Comment: That's a thought, I will look into that, thank you .